# porting std::wstring to gcc cygwin

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, cygwin

I am tryong to port a project written in Visual Studio 2010 from a Microsoft compiler to gcc Cygwin. My question is does gcc Cygwin or gcc support std::wstring ? Is there a work around for that ?

Comment: std::wstring is part of the standard, if I recall correctly. I don't see why cygwind wouldn't support it. Have you tested it?

Comment: @cassiorenan: However, it works _completely differently_ in Cygwin than in Visual Studio.  Easiest to assume they're unrelated classes.

Comment: Ah, I see. Disregard my answer, then. I'm not very familiar with Visual Studio's particularities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  It supports, But not easy.

> To support wstring, your platform needs to support a whole bunch of
>   wchar_t functionality.  q.v. Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales by
>   Langer and Kreft.
>
> It's really not enough to say "Hey, we've got wchar_t, and wchar_t
>   character traits, so we can turn on std::wstring."  The platform also
>   needs to provide support for the C++ wide character I/O:  wistream,
>   wostream, facet, cvt, locale.  And that's where things become
>   problematic.
>
> For Cygwin on Windows, the platform is Cygwin (and its amazingly cool
>   POSIX API layer) moreso than the WinAPI.
>
> ASIDE:  I'm not sure what the MinGW situation is, but since MinGW uses
>   WinAPI directly rather than having a more Unix-like POSIX API as the
>   approach, MinGW may not be in this Cygwin situation.
>
> Windows does support that functionality, *but* it appears that no one
>   has gone through the considerable effort of plumbing up Cygwin to use
>   those facilities.  (Those are the FooW routines, rather than the FooA
>   routines, in the WinAPI.  And there is a lot of work to get the locale
>   magic to work correctly.)
>
> Also, Windows uses a wchar_t of 2 bytes.  (Previous UCS-2, from the
>   Unicode
>   1.0 era.  Now with Vista and Win7, it's UTF-16.)  It would be a bit retro to have Cygwin use a 2 byte wchar_t, rather than a 4 byte
>   wchar_t.  That just makes everything a little more difficult.

*For further details, go to the **`gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help`**:*

Answer (score 1):

It does have support. This code compiles fine on g++ 4.8(As it should on any standard-conforming compiler):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  std::wstring s(L"Hello World!");
  std::wcout << s;
}
```